# Create task to reboot every week and make sure all tasks are safely stopped

Tags: cron, reboot, delayed-execution

I have tried the Crontab in root.

`30 21 * * 1 /sbin/shutdown -r now`

This code would restart my server at 21:30 every Monday which is all good.

However, I wish to know whether this would safely stop all tasks on that server as they cannot be abruptly stopped otherwise will cause corruption.  Would this provide an indefinite/long time for the tasks to safely stop and if not is there a way to allow this ?